# No output from script

Tags: bash, sh

I've edited my script, and get no more errors, however, the script is not executing to the Minecraft server, no announcement attempts are made at all for that matter. I'm rally puzzled. It's as if it's not running at all like the server is not running, but it is, and should be matching "is running" from the status command.

and code is:

```
#!/bin/bash

checkServer=$(/etc/init.d/minecraft status);
cd /.smc;

# Is the server even running?
if [ checkServer = *"is running"* ];
then

    # No count file? Create it.
    if [ ! -f /.smc/lastAnnouncement.txt ];
    then
            echo 0 < /.smc/lastAnnouncement.txt;
    fi

    # Load count
    lastAnn=$(cat /.smc/lastAnnouncement.txt);

    # ANNOUNCEMENTS
    announcement[0]='Dont  forget to check out http://fb.com/pyrexiacraftfans for news and updates';
    announcement[1]='Use our Facebook page to request land protection! Visit http://fb.com/pyrexiacraftfans';

    # Should we restart announcement que?
    if lastAnn == ${#announcement[@]}+1;
    then
            echo 0 < /.smc/lastAnnouncement.txt;
    fi

    # Send announcement
    sendAnnouncement=$(/etc/init.d/minecraft command say announcement[lastAnn]);

    # Next announcement count
    lastAnn=$((lastAnn+1));

    # Write next announacment count
    echo lastAnn < /.smc/lastAnnouncement.txt;

fi
```

Comment: Your script is wrong on so so so many levels, that it is not a shell script. It is not even logical. I'm correcting it and creating an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your script, ranging from useless semicolons to bad logic. The list of issues is so long that it's easier to post a corrected script than point out the issues (the other answers don't even come close to listing all the errors).

The corrected script is:

```
#!/bin/bash

checkServer=$(/etc/init.d/minecraft status)
cd /.smc

# Is the server even running?
if [[ $checkServer =~ "is running" ]]; then
    # No count file? Create it.
    if [ ! -f /.smc/lastAnnouncement.txt ]; then
            echo 0 > /.smc/lastAnnouncement.txt
    fi

    # Load count
    lastAnn=$(cat /.smc/lastAnnouncement.txt)

    # ANNOUNCEMENTS
    announcement[0]='Dont  forget to check out http://fb.com/pyrexiacraftfans for news and updates'
    announcement[1]='Use our Facebook page to request land protection! Visit http://fb.com/pyrexiacraftfans'

    # Send announcement
    sendAnnouncement=$(/etc/init.d/minecraft command say ${announcement[$lastAnn]})

    # Next announcement count
    ((++lastAnn))

    # Write next announacment count
    # Should we restart announcement que?
    if [[ $lastAnn -gt ${#announcement[@]} ]]; then
            echo 0 > /.smc/lastAnnouncement.txt
    else
            echo $lastAnn > /.smc/lastAnnouncement.txt
    fi
fi
```

The issues with your script (leaving aside the excess semicolons which don't hurt, just needless disk space wastage):

- missing `$` before variable name
- Incorrect string comparison. Use `=~` instead of `==`, `[[` instead of `[`, and remove `*` from both sides of the string `*"is running"*`

  ```
  if [ checkServer == *"is running"* ]
  ```
- Wrong redirection. you want to write to file, so `>`, not `<`. This is multiple times.

  ```
  echo 0 < /.smc/lastAnnouncement.txt;
  echo 0 < /.smc/lastAnnouncement.txt;
  ```
- Variable names missing `$` and wrong redirection

  ```
  echo lastAnn < /.smc/lastAnnouncement.txt;
  ```
- Easier increment with `((++lastAnn))`. Also this is invalid shell, as arithmetic needs `expr` command or `((...))` builtin

  ```
  lastAnn=$lastAnn+1;
  ```
- Missing `$` in variable name. Missing `test` , `[` or `[[`. Missing `expr` or `$((..))` for addition of `1`. `-eq` should be used instead of `==` for number equality. Logically this should use `-gt` to test against last index and `+1` is not required.

  ```
  if lastAnn == ${#announcement[@]}+1;
  ```

I won't go into the fact that the logic of writing the message queue index was incorrect, and would never loop back to `0`.

However, you did a wonderful job of trying to write a script. Many people don't even try.

**Edit** : I missed out a `{}` on the array variable usage on line 21 of the script above. Fixed.

Comment: Haha semicolons. Yeah, I write PHP, and I noticed the error with the loop as well. I'll look over that script tomorrow as first thing it throws is `/home/minecraft/startAnnouncement.sh: 33: [[: not found
`

Comment: @JordanThompson Use the script I wrote out, as the queue index saving logic in your script has a major bug.

Comment: @JordanThompson What line is the error on and what is the error?

Comment: Said it above. line 33. I fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if [ checkServer = *"is running"* ];
```

(Yes single equals sign)

Answer (score 0):

I believe your script has quite a few syntax error.

i.e. there is a problem in this line:

```
sendAnnouncement = $(/etc/init.d/minecraft command say $announcement[$lastAnn]);
```

Replace it with this:

```
sendAnnouncement=$(/etc/init.d/minecraft command say $announcement[$lastAnn])
```

bash (and other shells) doesn't allow spaces before and after the assignment operator `=`

Also this line:

```
lastAnn=$lastAnn+1;
```

should be replaced with:

```
lastAnn=$((lastAnn+1))
```

Comment: Everything looks good, but it isn't sending the announcement. ALl I get is

`****@pyrexia:/home/****# sh /home/minecraft/startAnnouncement.sh
****@pyrexia:/home/****#`

Comment: Better to post your modified script in your question so that I can suggest you something. btw which command is supposed to send the announcement?

Comment: Your script still has quite a few syntax issues. I can sure provide you a modified one as well. But I see that Samveen has also provided you one. Is that working for you or do you have some specific questions?

Comment: No it doesn't work, it errors out. Fixed the errors, but new ones just pop up, and since I didn't write it from my learning curve, having issues with it. Am a baby to Bash, I'm a web developer, but I am tired of the insecurities of SSH2 with PHP.

Comment: Sorry we can only point you in right direction but cannot write full script on your behalf. Let me know if you're having a specific issue, I can definitely help.

Comment: Didn't ask you too. Samveen did, and it has errors as well, but since I didn't write it, it's a little harder to debug. I think you misunderstand whats going on here.

Comment: I very well realize your difficulties in writing a shell script but as I said folks here tend to help for certain specific issues only.

Answer (score 0):

There are many errors:

First,

```
if [[ $checkserver == *"is running"* ]]
```

Using double [[...]] and a variable reference is $checkserver.
Then,

```
sendAnnouncement=$(
```

Without space.

Also,

```
if [ $lastAnn == $((${#announcement[@]}+1)) ]
```

Probably more...

Comment: First part works just fine... remove the double and go single and suddenly checkServer is a unknown operation. 

There is no whitespace in sendAnnouncement... its `sendAnnouncement=$()`

Also the last line works too. Did you even read the post?

Comment: It looks like I should have used more words. I meant that in $checkserver you were missing the $-sign and at sendAnnouncement I meant that you had to put the equal sign immediatly after the variable name. The last line, at the time didn't work. Of course I read the post, did you see I answered before you edited it?